# What are the limitations of a waters of hydration experiment?

Tags: stoichiometry

When a hydrated salt such as $\ce{CuSO4.5H2O}$ is subjected to heat, an anhydrous salt ($\ce{CuSO4}$) is produced. However the theoretical molar ratio of $\ce{H2O:CuSO4}$ and experimental molar ratio of $\ce{H2O:CuSO4}$ are not the same. Instead there is a percentage error, why does this occur? And how can we minimise this in this experiment?
The hydrated salt was left on hot plate at 70 degrees celsius for 25 mins.

Comment: Why, all experiments contain errors. If you want to know more, you have to tell us more. What is your experimental molar ratio, to begin with?

Comment: My experimental molar ratio of H2O: CuSO4 is 4:1

Comment: Then perhaps your experiment resulted in a _monohydrate_, rather than an anhydrous salt?

Comment: The hydrate contained 4 moles of water for every 1 mole of CuSO4. The expected was 5 moles of water for every 1 mole of CuSO4. It was not a monohydrate as there was more than 1 mole of water per mole of compound.

Comment: That's not what I was saying. See, what is it that's left ***after*** the heating? You seem to believe this is anhydrous CuSO4. What if this is not so?

Comment: Are you saying that maybe the hydrated salt was not heated enough, therefore not all water turned into steam therefore we were left with CuSO4.H2O + 4H2O (gas) instead of the intended CuSO4 + 5H2O (gas)

Comment: Yes, that seems plausible.

Comment: How was the amount of water evaporated measured?

Answer (score 3):

You can mention experimental details and how you achieved 1:4 ratio, which may explained if we know the maximum temperature of heating.  CuSO4.5H2O loses water of hydration in steps as a function of temperature showing that those five water molecules are not equivalent. In this figure from German Wiki, follow the green line (ignore blue). The y-axis is % loss in weight and x-axis is the temperature. It clearly shows that water is lost in steps. The labels read Mass change (loss of crystal water). If your heating temperature is not enough you are left with CuSO4.H2O.

[image: Loss of water]

Comment: Also I would mention that it might be difficult to keep the sample anhydrous both in the • sense and in a more trivial one. As the answer explain this matter is really linked to experimental details not to mention even humidity in the lab.